# Android proguard back arrow not displayed (although working in debug APK)

Tags: android, fragment, proguard

I have an Activity containing a fragment which shows a list of settings. When clicking on a list item, a fragment transaction is performed and the detail fragment is displayed. Also, the hamburger menu item is transformed into the back arrow (home as up).

In the debug APK, this works perfectly. However, in the release version, the hamburger menu is not transformed into the back arrow, but stays the same. When clicking the hamburger menu button from the detail fragment, the fragment is dismissed as expected.
The only problem is the display of the back arrow which is not shown in the release version using Proguard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution.
Since I am using DrawerArrowDrawable, I have to include the v7 support graphics library in the proguard file.

```
-keep class android.support.v7.graphics.** { *; }
```

Now the arrow drawable is displayed.

**UPDATE**: if you are using androidx:

```
-keep class androidx.appcompat.graphics.** { *; }
```